# Почему не работает код для работы со временем?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Исполняется сразу а не через 10 минут.

```
var time = moment()
var nextTime = time.add('10', 'minute')

if (time == nextTime){
  alert('Time to party! ' + time.format())
}
```

Как заставить работать код в определенное время?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь setTimeout и установите нужную задержку.

Comment: попробуйте так. 
var time = moment();
var nextTime = time.clone().add('10', 'minute'); 
setTimeout(function() { 
        alert('Time to party! ' + time.format())
        }, nextTime);

Comment: @batya
setTimeout() вторым аргументов ловит колличество миллесекунд а в nextTime лежит дата по сути. А мне просто нужно что бы в заданное мной время, исполнялся код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция `add` изменяет сам объект, а не создаёт новый. Поэтому `time` и `nextTime` одинаковые.

Вам надо клонировать объект и потом изменять

```
var nextTime = time.clone().add('10', 'minute')
```

Сравнивать при помощи `==` нельзя - используйте метод `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

Для создание `nextTime` надо создать новый объект `moment`.
Вот как надо установить `nextTime`:

```
var nextTime = moment(time).add(10, 'minute');
```

Вот пример:

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script>
 
 var time = moment();
 var nextTime = moment(time).add(10, 'minute');
 console.log(time);
 console.log(nextTime);
 
 setTimeout(function() { 
        alert('Time to party! ' + time.format())
        }, 10000);
  
</script>
```

А для задержки кода в `javascript` есть метод [setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval).