# Как с помощью diff сравить 2 даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Как с помощью метода `diff`, правильно сравнить 2 даты?

```js
var time = moment()
var nextTime = time.clone().add('10', 'minute')

if (time == nextTime) {
  alert('Time to party! ' + time.format())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не работает код для работы со временем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682596/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: @Darth, нет, это код из одного из ответов оттуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Метод `diff()` вычисляет разницу между двумя датами**.

ПО умолчанию разница считается в миллисекундах, но также может быть возвращена в днях, месяцах, годах и прочее.

Первым аргументом он принимает дату. Размерность промежутка может быть указана вторым аргументом. Если он не указан, то по умолчанию используются миллисекунды. Следующий пример показывают использование метода `diff()`.

```js
var dateB = moment('2017-11-11');
var dateC = moment('2017-10-11');

console.log('Разница в ', dateB.diff(dateC), 'миллисекунд');
console.log('Разница в ', dateB.diff(dateC, 'days'), 'дней');
console.log('Разница в ', dateB.diff(dateC, 'months'), 'месяцев');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Сравнение дат**.

Moment.js также предоставляет методы для сравнения дат - isBefore(), isAfter() и isSame(). Соответственно своим названиям, они возвращают булево значение, если одна из дат была до, после, или же они равны. Пример использования isAfter() показан ниже.

```js
console.log(moment('2010-09-20').isAfter('2010-10-19')); // возвращает false
console.log(moment('2010-11-20').isAfter('2010-10-19')); // возвращает true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Побольше бы таких ответов! Спасибо!